# sharepoing rounded corner jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I trying to using the jquery plugin of rounded corner, directly into the masterpage (v4.master)

here is the code:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/js/jquery.js" runat="server"/> <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/js/corner.js" runat="server"/> <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/js/customScript.js" runat="server"/>
```

Link"
corner.js: 
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

customScript.js:
$(function(){
    $("div.s4-widecontentarea").corner("10px");
});

but its not effecting on div.

Firebug Console showing following error is:

TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined
[Break On This Error]

if (jQuery.browser.msie) this.style.zoom = 1; // force 'hasLayout' in IE

any help???
how can I use the plugin of rounded corner, or any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.browser is depricited since 1.3](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) and I am sure you are using latest one. Please check rounded corner plugin for its requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a document.ready tag in your custom script.

As an alternative I've used css3pie in pervious SharePoint projects.  Add the .htc file to the layouts folder and reference it that way rather than in the style library

http://css3pie.com/